# Can you get the number of users in on_ready? In a cog

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im trying to get the bots status to say the amount of people in all the servers that its in. Example: Status: Watching 82 people | $cmds

Heres what ive tried:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('{0.user} has awoken!'.format(self.bot))
        await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name = f"{self.bot.users} people | $cmds"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Note that you should first add `Bot.wait_until_ready` so the cache is done loading.

One way of doing so:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
    
    total_members = 0
    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
        total_members += guild.member_count

    await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name = f"{total_members} people | $cmds"))
```

Another way

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

    members = [x for x in self.bot.get_all_members()] # Doing this to "flatten" the generator
    total_members = len(members)

    await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name = f"{total_members} people | $cmds"))
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds)
- [`Guild.member_count`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.member_count)
- [`Bot.get_all_members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members)

Comment: I've tried both solutions, neither of which changes the status of the bot. Is this because the cog is loaded after the main `on_ready` function is called in my main `.py` file?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if you’re loading the extension on the on_ready event the event inside the cog will not be called